# Error with bukkit from get online players size

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit, minecraft-forge

```
Error:(14, 46) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method size()
  location: class org.bukkit.entity.Player[] <- this is coming from Bukkit.getServer().getOnlinePlayers().size();
<Spigot API Version  - 1.13, Java 1.8>
```

Comment: Did you mean `.length` instead of `.size()`?

Comment: if i am sure .length isnt there.

Comment: can you show the code snippet?